# If {$a_n$} is a sequence of natural number, can we write {$a_n$} $\in\mathbb N$?

Tags: notation

If {$a_n$} is a sequence of natural numbers, can we write {$a_n$} $\in\mathbb N$ ?
Thanks.

${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: That's abuse of notation. Sometimes, a sequence is written as $$\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset \mathbb N$$ That too is abuse of notation, but perhaps a little clearer.

Comment: Maybe something like $\{a_n\}\in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ should be possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. A sequence of natural numbers is a function from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$. The notation $\{a_n\}\in\Bbb N$, says that the object $\{a_n\}$ is a natural number. In fact it’s a set with one element, that being a particular term of the sequence, or a sloppy abbreviation for $\{a_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, in which case it’s a set of natural numbers. In neither case is it a natural number **or** a sequence of natural numbers.